# add a picture in a panel for mfc ribbon menu

Tags: visual-c++, ribbon, mfc-feature-pack

I am trying to add a picture in a panel in mfc ribbon menu and could not find a function. The basic idea is to add a big picture showing device type when the device type change. I am using visual c++ 2010 and 2013. Any suggestion?

Comment: have you found the solution for this? also IMO it is not clear if you want to add a button/icon to show some information (device type)  or if you want the image to be set as background. the former is quite easier as you just need to add the button with the imag and then change the image number during execution, the latter will make you deal with drawing right on the CWnd using CDC, brush and stuff. please clarify what you want and maybe draw also something on paint to show which result you actually want

Comment: I need to add a big image to show the type of different device selected by users. I ended up to add a docking panel on the side of the screen to display the image.

Comment: write your solution then so the question can be closed =)